# How to check logged event on Google/Firebase Analytics console?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have logged an [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events) to Analytics using-

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("TestAudio")
    .setAction("AudioClick")
    .build());
```

but I am not able to see it on console although my app is properly integrated and showing other data.
[image]

Comment: is this Firebase Analytics or Google Analytics?

Comment: @IshaanKumar Google Analytics screenshot

Comment: @IshaanKumar Both Google and Firebase analytics showing same data as they r linked!

Comment: not familiar with Google Analytics.....knows only about Firebase sorry.

Comment: @IshaanKumar Firebase analytics is showing same data..i updated question..tell me how to check on firebase?

Comment: Firebase Analytics has a 24 hour delay to process your event data. But you can check the realtime data at the "Streamview" option on the console menu.

Comment: @GersonLCSJunior not able to see data even after 24 hours.. Should the data be visible under existing events only as shown in screenshot?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper sorry, I just saw your other reply saying that you're using Google Analytics SDK. You'll need to use the Firebase Analytics SDK in order to send events to Firebase. Also, I'd recommend that you set up the debugview on Firebase, as it'll help you debug your implementation. You can refer to the docs shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: @GersonLCSJunior The screenshot I shared above is of Google analytics.. even there I can't see my custom  events

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper That's because the Google Analytics SDK only sends events to the legacy Mobile Property on GA, which is being deprecated. It seems you're either using a App + Web property or the new "Apps" property on Google Analytics. Both of them only receive data from the Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from my android project:

```
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, content_type);
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, b)
```

This event is properly logged by Firebase and shown in `select_content > content_type` in Firebase Analytics

Comment: I am using - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events and my google and firebase analytics linked!

Comment: Familiar with Firebase Analytics, this is Google Analytics. You should keep in mind that analytics may take time to appear in your console. Its not instant.